# Searching a city in Genymotion Mapping Service currently not working

Tags: android, genymotion, genymotion-gps

Searching a city using the "Search" button in Mapping Service in Genymotion emulator is currently not working and not updating the map with the proper latitudes and longitudes. I'm using version 2.12.2.

[image]

I'm currently zooming out from Iceland and going to the city that I want to go to manually since the search is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion `2.12.2` suffers from **Google Maps API** changes which are breaking the location search.

Hopefully it is fixed in Genymotion `3.0.0` where the GPS widget has been entirely redesigned and don't use Google Maps anymore.

*Note:If you need this feature, upgrading is your only option.*